# How to get selected value of a combobox in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have `employee_ID` in combo box list. On change of the `e_ID` I want the selected value to be show in the `name` and `address` field using VBA Access code.

How can I get this?

Comment: Is `e_ID` = `employee_ID`? Where do `name` and `address` come from? What did you try already? Please show us your code.

Comment: Yeah without seeing anything else its hard to give you an answer. It should be as easy as referencing other columns in your combobox (if theyre there) or doing some simple dlookups with your EID value.